# Prove $M(M+I)^{-1}M \succeq \frac{1}{2}I$ for any PSD matrix $M \succeq I$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality

For any $n \times n$ symmetrix matrices A, B, we define $A \succeq B$ if and only if $v^TAv \succeq v^TBv$ for all $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: Do you mean for all $v\in \mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: @RyanGreyling Right! Edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $M \succeq I$, $M$ is PD so it is invertible. We have $M^2 \succeq I$ and then $M \succeq M^{-1}$. From this and the fact that $M \succeq I$ we have $$2M \succeq M+I \succeq M^{-1}+I$$ The left and right sides of this inequality yield $$M \succeq \frac{1}{2}I+\frac{1}{2}M^{-1}$$ $$M \succeq \frac{1}{2}M^{-1}(M+I)$$ $$M(M+I)^{-1}M \succeq \frac{1}{2}I$$

Comment: When solving problems like this I find that it's easiest to assume that the end statement is true, and then work backwards from there to prove the initial condition. The written proof is just the reverse of this process.

Comment: Being positive definite implies invertibility. Being PSD does not. However, you can deduce that $M$ is positive definite from $M \succeq I$. In particular, if $v \neq 0$, then $v^\top M v \ge v^\top I v = \|v\|^2 > 0$. Similar reasoning will also justify the existence of $(M + I)^{-1}$.

Comment: Thanks @TheoBendit , edited my answer to clarify that $M$ is PD.